# Radio malfunction

Tags: electrical, audio, dodge, caliber

I have a 2012 Dodge caliber and my radio plays music, then suddenly stops for a couple seconds, and then plays music again.  It continually does this as long as the radio is on and playing some type of music. It doesn't matter whether it's radio, through the aux cord, or CD.  Does anyone know what is wrong or have any suggestions on how to fix my problem?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It sounds like you're saying it does this "only when connected" ... is that through Bluetooth? Or could you clarify?

Comment: No it does that with the radio, the CD player or the aux cord doesn’t matter as long as the radio is on and there’s music to be played it goes off for a couple seconds then starts playing the music again then goes off, its the same thing repeatedly

Comment: Does the radio re-initialize (like when you first start the car) or does it just not make any sound?

Comment: Does only the audio quit, or does the radio turn off (go dark) as well?

Comment: The radio re-initializes and it’s just the audio all other functions on the radio are working

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly the radio unit itself is otherwise fully functional with the exception of the audio cutting in and out. It sounds like an internal power supply issue with the amplifier like a overheating component that quits when it hot and when it cools it starts working again. It could also be a bad solder joint in the same area of the circuit board. Both can have the same effect.  Anybody who is extremely good (i.e: a technician) with electronics could confirm this and suggest a course of action.